# How to Check if a File Path is Valid

Tags: c#

I have a string that is in the registry that can either point to an `.exe`, `.txt` along with certain command line arguments like:

```
C:\\PAthtoTheExe\program1.exe -arg1 -arg2
```

How do I determine if the "program1.exe" is a valid executable, IE that it points to an existing file? (this could be removed if the user uninstalls the application for eg:)

I don't like the idea of parsing out the arguments, because right now, the path can either point to an `.exe` or `.txt` or a `.url`. I would have to put in a long if else to do that.

Comment: Why don't up put all possible extensions in a collection or enum and loop through that to determine the type of file you got? Or use the System.Path namespace to manipulate your path and get filenames, extensions etc from the string?

Answer (score 1):

There's a

```
File.Exists( path );
```

method that will return `true` if the filename exists. It won't tell you if the file contains a valid executable, though.

You can separate the path from the other arguments using

```
string tokens[] = registry_value.Split( ' ' );
```

then passing the first token to `File.Exists()`

Comment: @user1202434 you can try it first :D

Comment: @user1202434 - that will make things messy... a regular expression (the exact syntax of which is beyond my abilities, I regret) or, preferably, enclosing the filename in doublequotes is the traditional approach.